# GridView problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

this is the first time i try asp.net programming so i face this problem:

i have several services that i need to communicate with and retrieve info from....
this info need to be shown to the client.

i decided to use a GridView control to display my data

**Why do i need a grid view?**

i need a gridview to view a List that i retrieve from a remote web service.
   i read that the grid view is the best choice there is to displaying data,, better than  the Table and better from The Letteral control....

**What is the problem?**

i cant find a way to bind the GridView with my object,, although i set the
     gridview.datasource = List/////
     gridview.databind()

but it didnt work.

**in this section i have more than one question:**

1. do i have to do the binding between the grid view and the car list in the code (c#)
   or do is it better to do it in the Markup ? and how can i make such a binding?
2. when i used the raw DataSet from the webservice it worked just fine .... but i dont think the better way is to use the data set,,, and that is way i used the encapsulation
   so i dont know if it is better or not (silly question ;) )

another point is that i tested the allow sorting and allow paging on the grid view when i test it on a data from my database using ajax but it didnt work?????

any one can help i spend a very long time trying to solve the problem,, with no luck

***this is the code am using***

```
List<Car> test = BL.carFilterOnYearofmanuf(1980);
GridView1.DataSource = test;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Can you post some example code that you are using?

Comment: check the AutogenerateColumn property in gridview declaration.

Answer (score 4):

i might have missed out an important information about the error mesg i had it was:

"The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any
properties or attributes from which to generate columns. Ensure that your
data source has content."

and i fixed the problem by changing the fields in my (Car) class into attributes:

public int Id;

to

public int Id{ get; set; }

and this problem was fixed,,, i didnt solve the sorting nor paging problem yet

Answer (score 0):

To answer 1 of your points:

1) Your correct, you can simply bind to the griview using the following code:

```
Gridview1.datasource = List;
Gridview1.databind();
```

**List** needs to be one of the following types (taken from the MSDN documentation)

- A DataTable
- A DataView
- A DataSet
- A DataViewManager
- Any component that implements the IListSource interface
- Any component that implements the IList interface

On your other point, I personally use the Jquery tablesorter plugin to do sorting on gridviews, and find it very good for sorting.

Comment: i added the code sample am using to my question... hope u could help